# Format Date (25 Jul) using Javascript Object Model

Tags: javascript

I am using sp2013 and building display templates. I would like to build a locig in javascript object model to get a date field back and display it on a page e.g.

var itemDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "Created");

This displays on the page by default as: Thu Jul 25 09:30:07 PDT 2013

I want to display it as: 25 Jul

How do i format a date in javascript?

Comment: Change the fields property to DateOnly=True, it will give you somthing like: 25/6/2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var d=new Date("Thu Jul 25 09:30:07 PDT 2013");
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var yourNiceDate= d.getDate()+" "+monthNames[d.getMonth()];
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for working with dates. Nk SP's solution will, of course, work fine for your current question, but moment gives you a lot of flexibility for working with dates and formatting them.

Here is an example (note jQuery is not a requirement):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var d = new Date("Thu Jul 25 09:30:07 PDT 2013");
 $("#display1").html(moment(d).format("DD, MM"));
 $("#display2").html(moment(d).format("DD, MMM"));
 $("#display3").html(moment(d).format("DD, MMM, YYYY"));
 $("#display4").html(moment(d).format("LLLL"));
 $("#display5").html(moment(d).fromNow());
});
```

Output:

> 25, 07
>  25, Jul
>  25, Jul, 2013
>  Thursday, July 25 2013 12:30
>   PM
>  9 months ago

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uHER4/

Comment: We posted our answers at the same time :) cheers for the same suggestion. Moment.js is an indispensable tool

Comment: +1 one on your answer, as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to work with dates in javascript, I strongly recommend using the excellent [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/). It makes formatting dates a snap.

```
var d = moment("Thu Jul 25 09:30:07 PDT 2013");
d.format("DD MMM"); // "25 Jul"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format does not vary from what you presented, you could use split, and access the desired elements in array notation.

```
itemDate = itemDate.split(" ");
itemDate = itemDate[1] + " " + itemDate[2];
```

You lose any date properties by doing this, so if the other elements of the date object are important you're probably better off with moment.js.